# Separately edit left and right audio track channels in Python

Tags: python, audio, channel

How can I separately edit the left ear channel and right ear channel of a .wav or mp3 audio track? What are some recommended python audio editing tools to go about this.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic on stackoverflow, you should consider asking at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it before, but I've heard good things about [pydub](http://pydub.com/).